# How can I change the foreground color of the words of a ToolTip using Gmap.net?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

How can I change the foreground color of the words of a ToolTip using Gmap.net?

```
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Mark_Latitude[Mark_Longitude.Count - 1]), Convert.ToDouble(Mark_Longitude[Mark_Longitude.Count - 1])),GMarkerGoogleType.green);
GMapOverlay gMapOverlay = new GMapOverlay("polygons");
gMapOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
marker.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.OnMouseOver;
marker.ToolTip = new GMapBaloonToolTip(marker);
Brush ToolTipBackColor = new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent);
Font f = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
ToolTipBackColor.GetType();
marker.ToolTip.Stroke.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 0);
marker.ToolTip.Font = f;
marker.ToolTip.Fill = ToolTipBackColor;    
marker.ToolTipText = ":" + Mark_Longitude[Mark_Longitude.Count - 1] + " :" + Mark_Latitude[Mark_Latitude.Count - 1];
```

A picture to illustrate the problem follows:

[image]

Comment: The question was misleading. The purpose was to change the foreground color of words in a ToolTip. It was not about getting the ToolTip to change the foreground color.

Comment: Yes，I want to change foreground color of words in a ToolTip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to set the `Foreground` property:

```
marker.ToolTip.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
```